# Error: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am getting this error in Chrome's Developer Tools:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

This error is referencing this line of my `main.js` file. These two lines are both causing this error to happen:

```
jQuery("#signupfrm").fadeToggle('fast',function(){
jQuery("#loginfrm").fadeToggle('fast',function(){
```

You can replicate this by going **[here](http://portal.escalateinternet.com/cart.php?a=add&pid=389)**.

Try switching between the "New Customer" and "Current Customer" tabs and nothing will happen.  It just causes the errors I mentioned above.

Does anyone know what needs to be edited to fix this?

Comment: You're probably missing the `selectBoxIt` plugin, or that's another error?

Comment: I have the javascript and css files for `selectBoxIt` referenced on that page...

Comment: I was watching your html code and you are loading 2 times the jquery library,  from includes/jscript/jquery.js and http://www.escalateinternet.com/js/jquery.js,  delete the second and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using jQuery version 1.3.2, while [`fadeToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) method was added in 1.4.4. So you should upgrade jQuery or use other combination of [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)/[`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).